# GDB in Emacs 24 messed up

Tags: emacs, gdb, emacs24, emacs23, gud

I am using emacs `24.5.1` and GDB `7.10` in conjunction with the GUD integration.

I am starting GUD with the following bash command:

```
emacs --eval "(gdb \"gdb -i=mi --fullname --cd=`pwd` -args $*\")" &
```

I have set the following variables

- `'(gdb-show-main t)`

With the previous version of emacs (23), I had two windows/buffers:

1. Output of the program being run AND the GUD prompt `(gdb)`
2. The code/source window showing the code and where the debugger is at

```
+--------------+
| *gud-binary* |
+--------------+
|  source.cpp  |
+--------------+
```

Whenever I stepped in the `*gud-binary*` window in emacs 23, the result was shown in the source window below.

What's strange in emacs 24 is that emacs replaces the `*gud-binary*` buffer with the source buffer whenever I step in gdb. It seems that every buffer is displayed in the first window. So, the second window actually doesn't have any function at all.

How can I fix that?